# Node JS - Taking data from anchor tag in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am getting data from this route in my page welcomeuser

```
router.get('/welcomeuser', async(req,res)=>{
    const alluser1 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const query = `select * from signin where username=?`;
        connection.query(query,passedvalue,(err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(new Error('Something Went Wrong+:' + err));
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
    console.log(alluser1,alluser2,alluser3,alluser4);
    res.render('./PATIENT/welcomeuser', {value1: alluser4});
});
```

Now I want to take the userid from the **value1** that comes to the welcomeuser.ejs page using this anchor tag. How Can I do So?
This is a LINE from the above welcomepage.ejs in which i am getting the whole data.

```
<li>
    <a href="/yourprofile"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Your Profile</a>
</li>
```

Comment: how are you making a `GET` request to `/welcomeuser ` from your client?

Comment: I use form and put method as GET in it.

Answer (score 1):

button on some page

```js
<li>
    <a href="/yourprofile?userId={{userId}}"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Your Profile</a>
</li>
```

user clicks the above button and goes to the profile page. The profile page has userId as a query parameter.

The url path looks like this: `/yourprofile?userId=xxxx`;

Below method is called on page load which makes a `GET` request to your node server with the userId value grabbed from the query parameter.

```js
// this is where you are making a GET request
function getUserDetails() {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const userId = urlParams.get('userId');
  // call the backend API with the userId param
}
```

now we can use this userId to request data from the `/welcomeuser` endpoint with userId as `/welcomeuser?userId=xxxx`

```js
router.get('/welcomeuser', async(req,res)=>{
    const userId = req.query.userId; // userId from query
    const alluser1 = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const query = `select * from signin where username=?`;
        connection.query(query,passedvalue,(err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(new Error('Something Went Wrong+:' + err));
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
    console.log(alluser1,alluser2,alluser3,alluser4);
    res.render('./PATIENT/welcomeuser', {value1: alluser4});
});
```